# Get reply mail to my server for a mail sent through php mail function

Tags: php, email, imap

I am developing a system to send mail to all of our clients. If they reply to that mail, I want to retrieve the reply mails to my server. There is a way to connect through the IMAP/POP3 server, But it is taking a long time to load the mails. Is there any way to get the reply mails directly to my server. or ay other alternate way to get the mails fastly through IMAP

Please Help me in solving this issue

Comment: Post your code (don't forget to change your connection details to dummy data), so people can see if it can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Set your own mail server on your server |or|

Only loads the headers of the emails, check the property in_reply_to to know if the email is a reply from your sent email and download only the one you want |or|

Download the email during the night with a cron (if you are using linux), you'll then have all the email from the last day on your server in the morning

Answer (score 0):

If you have your mail server set up already, then I would recommend using a library like `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` to read and parse your incoming messages.  Parsing mail can be really complicated, and Zend takes a lot of the pain out of implementing tools to read incoming mail.

If retrieving mail is slow, then I would also recommend processing mail with a cron on a regular basis, depending on how often you need to reference the information sent via email.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html